# Clear invalid status after form submit

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to submit form using angular, form is successfully submitted. 
Issue  is after form submit, drop down shows as a invalid state. How to remove it.

```
<form class="form-inline" name="form" #invoiceheaderform="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="invoiceheaderform.form.valid && fileNameList();">
<label for="bank" class="lb-adj">Banks</label>
<select class="form-control fix-dropdown" required   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':invoiceheaderform.submitted && orgname.invalid}" #orgname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="orgNameModel.orgName" name="orgName"> 
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
   <option *ngFor="let bank of orgNameModel | async">{{bank}}</option> 
</select>
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="disableRunButton" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 expad">Search</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: have you used `form.reset()`?

Comment: yes. i used reset function also. after form reset issue occurred

Answer (score 0):

try this, after your form is submitted successfully, change your variable to `undefined`

```
this.orgNameModel.orgName = undefined;
```

latest angular forms with `reset()` is not working as expected.

**EDIT**

your using `async` for options may be that is effecting the functionality.Try to remove `async` and provide an array to the options

```
<select class="form-control fix-dropdown" required   [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':invoiceheaderform.submitted && orgname.invalid}" #orgname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="orgNameModel.orgName" name="orgName"> 
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
   <option *ngFor="let bank of orgNameModel">{{bank}}</option> 
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
orgNameModel:any = [];
//assign the list of banks to orgNameModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first `<option>` tag like this -

```
  <option value="undefined" disabled="true">--Select--</option>
```